# WebDriver Trying To Capture Message on Button Event

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver, testng, browser-automation

Selenium WebDriver Automation and need a help for the below query -

Initially I was doing below : `wt=webdriverWait` and `wd =webdriver`

```
wt.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("[class=\"infoMessage\"],[class=\"errorMessage\"]")).getText();

wd.findElement(By.cssSelector("[class=\"infoMessage\"],[class=\"errorMessage\"]")).getText();
```

to validate if the test was pass or fail as **infoMessage** is triggered when the event is successful and **errorMessage** when the event results in failure .

**the above was working perfectly fine earlier releases , but now there was recent change in GUI to optimize the performance due to which the InfoMessage flashes out from DOM immediately and the WebDriver is not able to locate it or StaleReferenceException .**

I tried to resolve by introducing explicit delays (Thread.sleep) and Implicit Delays
but still I am unable to trace the infoMessage.
Please can you suggest me any solution for the above I am attaching the DOM below .

```
<div id="packetSniffingMessages">
  <table id="packetSniffingMessages">
   <tbody>
      <tr class="**infoMessage**">
       <td>Action Successful </td>
    </tr>


<div id="packetSniffingMessages">
  <table id="packetSniffingMessages">
     <tbody>
        <tr class="**errorMessage**">
            <td>
                    Failed to Start
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now , as Mentioned earlier , the moment I click on the submit button , **infoMessage** is displayed but in **seconds/millisecs**  it flashes off from the DOM.

and I am left with below.

```
<div id="packetSniffingMessages">

 <div id="packetSniffingMessages"></div>

</div>
```

**NOTE: FOR , errorMessage I am able to fetch the text as it remains as it was working earlier .**

Please advise.

Comment: Can u try with `wt.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//tr[contains(@class,'infoMessage')]/td")).getText();` after click.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code to wait for the **visibility of the element and then fetching the text:**

```
WebDriverWait wt = new WebDriverWait(wd,10);
String text = wt.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("[class=\"infoMessage\"],[class=\"errorMessage\"]"))).getText();
System.out.println(text);
```

Comment: Hi Subh, thanks for the reply I tried with the above code but still I am facing same issues as earlier.
I am adding few more details hope this might help
bold Manual Steps are like:  1-Enter the Text box (some value) .2- Click on Start Button {if the value entered is invalid "errorMessage" class displays the error message to the user, else for valid value;  on start click button the UI processes it to display the device-screen , and at the same moment infoMessage class is displayed}